Under which scope should we calculate fuel usage from rented vehicles
As a global company with 13 subsidiaries, we heavily rely on rented vehicles and air travel providers to support our operations. While we maintain our own fleet, our technicians often fly to project locations and subsequently rent vehicles in the countries where we operate. Additionally, not all of our subsidiaries have their own vehicle fleets.
Our previous Environmental Coordinator classified fuel usage for rented vehicles under Scope 1, considering our technicians' mobility as part of our core processes. However, according to the GHG Protocol, this should fall under Scope 3, specifically within the category of Business Travel. Could you please clarify which approach is correct?

i think this question is a better fit over at https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/ maybe this question should be migrated.
